# limits with L'hopitals rule

Tags: calculus, limits

can u guys help me evaluate the limit of
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} x \arctan{\frac{1}{x}}$$ 
I know that it's 1 but I need to make sure that my steps are right so I want details please , thank you

Comment: You do know that this limit can also be calculated with the use of standard limits instead of L'Hospital?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\arctan (\frac 1 x) =\lim_{y \to 0} \frac {\arctan y} y=\lim_{y \to 0} \frac 1 {1+y^{2}}=1$ by L'Hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 1):

Your steps ? I see no steps !

We have $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \arctan{\frac{1}{x}}= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\arctan t}{t}.$

Now L'Hospital.

Comment: can you explain to me what you did in the first step ? arctan t / t